# AWS Lex deploy-a-web-ui-for-your-chatbot template doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am a beginner for AWS chat bot. I am following https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-a-web-ui-for-your-chatbot/ in creating the chat bot. But me deploying by launching the stack button with lex-webui sample chat bot works fine. To test the bot by clicking webApp url launches the chat bot with full screen and give me this question

**"You can ask me for help ordering flowers. Just type "Buy flowers" or click on the mic and say it."**

Now typing Buy flowers gives me this error

**"Sorry, I was unable to process your message. Try again later."**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the repository for `aws-lex-web-ui` and found the error listed in the following file: [actions.js](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui/blob/233153d9e36ed542fb999aee5814a3059a78ae00/lex-web-ui/src/store/actions.js#L601)

It is likely that the issue is due to the client-side application not being able to communicate with the server-side services. Off the cuff, this could be due to

1. incorrect or missing endpoint in the client-side configuration
2. incorrect or missing credentials in the client-side configuration
3. incorrect or missing security group configuration on the server-side

There should be some additional information relating to the error that's printed. Could you share that to help with debugging?